# What are $b$ and $c$ if $\int^1_0e^x \left[c\ln(x^2+1)+\frac{bx}{x^2+1} \right]dx=\frac{be}{2}\ln2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I came across a question today...

> Let $F(x) =  e^x \left(c\ln(x^2+1)+\dfrac{bx}{x^2+1} \right)$. If $\displaystyle \int^1_0F(x)\,dx=\dfrac{b e}{2}\ln2$ then the values of $c$ and $b$ can be:
>   Options are
>
> 1. $c=1, b=2$
> 2. $c=2, b=3$
> 3. $c=1/2, b=1$
> 4. $c=1/3, b=1/2$

I first tried to integrate $F(x)$. I got...$$\int F(x)dx=c e^x\ln(1+x^2)+(b-2c) \int \dfrac{x e^xdx}{x^2+1}.$$

Well ...now what? I have no idea how to solve it now?  Is it even a right way to do such a question?

Comment: Substitute the given options and simplify. The substitution which yields $\text{True}$ upon simplification is the right one.

Comment: @dbanet can i substitute in the integral?

Comment: Sure. But oh well, I didn't notice your primitive. Please notice your integrand is not a differential form.

Comment: Additionally, since the integration you are originally asked to perform is definite, you should not end up with expressions involving $x$.

Comment: @dbanet that's the problem with what i tried...it ended up involving x

Comment: If $f$ is your primitive such that $f'=F$, then you should arrive to the equation $$f(1)-f(0)=be\log(2)/2$$ due to the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that integration by parts gives
$$\int_0^1\frac{bxe^{x}dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{be}{2}\ln2-\frac b2\int_0^1e^x
\ln\left(1+x^2\right)dx.$$
Hence your equation is equivalent to
$$\left(c-\frac b2\right)\int_0^1e^x
\ln\left(1+x^2\right)dx=0.$$
I hope the rest is clear.